# Multiple group expressions in list (ssrs 2005)

Tags: list, expression, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I have a problem with group expressions in a list. I want to use two expressions:

```
=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/3)' and '=Cint(Fields!kpilevel.Value)
```

They work both individually, but when I insert them together only 1 works. I inserted them like this: img718.imageshack.us/img718/736/problemxq.png

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance, Kris

---

EDIT: Better Explanation

Mark you are right, I didn't explain it very well.

I want to place the data in a matrix, with a maximum of three columns per row, and I want to sort my data with the expression: =Cint(Fields!kpilevel.Value). Therefore I want to use both the expressions: Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/3) and Cint(Fields!kpilevel.Value).

But I cant get the right output. I tried to place my grouping and sorting expressions, in multiple ways. With different results:

Last situation: http://img257.imageshack.us/img257/5765/10569159.png (Image Removed)

Different output:

---

**List - Properties**

Sorting: `=Cint(Fields!kpilevel.Value) ascending`

**List - Grouping and Sorting Properties**

Group on:

```
=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/3)

=Cint(Fields!kpilevel.Value)
```

Sorting:

```
=Cint(Fields!kpilevel.Value) ascending
```

**Matrix columngroup - Grouping and Sorting Properties**

Group on:

```
=RowNumber("list1_Details_Group")
```

**Output: (ungrouped but sorted)**

1

2

3

4

etc

---

**List - Properties**

-

**List - Grouping and Sorting Properties**

Group on:

```
=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/3)

=Cint(Fields!kpilevel.Value)
```

Sorting:

```
=Cint(Fields!kpilevel.Value) ascending
```

**Matrix columngroup - Grouping and Sorting Properties**

Group on:

```
=RowNumber("list1_Details_Group")
```

**Output: (ungrouped & unsorted)**

1

2

9

10

etc

---

**List - Properties**

Sorting:

```
=Cint(Fields!kpilevel.Value) ascending
```

**List - Grouping and Sorting Properties**

Group on:

```
=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/3)
```

**Matrix columngroup - Grouping and Sorting Properties**

Group on:

```
=RowNumber("list1_Details_Group")
```

**Output: (grouped but unsorted)**

1  2  9

4  7  3

10  etc

---

**List - Properties**

-

**List - Grouping and Sorting Properties**

Group on:

```
=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/3)
```

**Matrix columngroup - Grouping and Sorting Properties**

Group on:

```
=RowNumber("list1_Details_Group")
```

Sorting:

```
=Cint(Fields!kpilevel.Value)
```

Output: (grouped but strangly sorted)

1   2   9

10  11  13

3   4   7

12

---

I hope this makes it clearer, Kris

Comment: Much clearer, thanks - I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this, I have noticed some rather strange effects when grouping by functions of data items in matrixes in SSRS, rather than by data items themselves.

For this reason, in this context I would recommend:

- using a table rather than a matrix
- sorting the table (or the dataset) by Cint(Fields!kpilevel.Value)
- grouping the table by Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/3)
- include group footer rows only (no table header/footer, details or group header)
- have 3 columns in the report
- have conditional output in each cell, dependant on whether RowNumber(Nothing) mod 3 equals 0, 1 or 2

Alternatively, if it *has* to be done in a matrix, then (assuming you're using a SQL data source) I would recommend

- grouping the query by int(kpilevel)
- ordering the query output by int(kpilevel)
- including display_row and display_column values in the query, defined as the ceiling of the rownumber/3 and the modulus of the rownumber with 3, respectively
- defining the row and column groups of your matrix as the display_row and display_column values from the query, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! I sorted the data with the command: ORDER BY KPILevel, in the Query designer