# SSRS: how to group by multiple parameters

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, group-by

I need to create a report using SSRS, it needs dynamicly group by the matrix.
I added a parameter(name: ColumnData) for it and the available value like 'Date', 'Type', 'ServerName',
for a single value, I can edit the group by expression to

```
=Fields(Parameter!ColumnData.Value).Value
```

but when the parameter is multiple, Parameter!ColumnData.Value would return a list and I need to use like that:

```
==Fields(Parameter!ColumnData.Value(0)).Value & Fields(Parameter!ColumnData.Value(1)).Value
```

but it's not what I want as I need to indicate the index manually...
Anyone knows how to use the multiple parameters in the group by expression?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you deselect `'Allow multiple values'` in the Parameter properties, your group by expression should work as is.
You will then be able to group by the selected value from the parameter.

(It will then not be possible to choose more than one of the values).
But it only makes sense to group on one value, or?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this topic, but my solution was simple. I had to group by multiply fields, and ended using something like this:

```
<GroupExpression>=Fields!ColumnName1.Value</GroupExpression>
<GroupExpression>=Fields!ColumnName2.Value</GroupExpression>    
<GroupExpression>=Fields!ColumnName3.Value</GroupExpression>
```

But this may not be what you are looking for since you wanted something more generic.

You can check this answer as it has some advices about matrix:
[Multiple group expressions in list (ssrs 2005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006956/multiple-group-expressions-in-list-ssrs-2005)

Hope that helps.